# Edge addon can not capture audio on some Windows version

Tags: microsoft-edge

We are a developer of Edge addon and Chrome extension, we have some issue reported by the users that in some Windows versions our addon/extension Edge and Chrome can not capture the audio,

Windows 10 1909, Edge can not use "chrome.tabCapture.capture" to record the browser's audio. I think it is a bug. On MacOS, it works.

You can test the following extensions:

edge：https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/ejfccgmelcclnoadalcepdmnpgcnglfc

chrome： https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aha-music-music-identifie/dpacanjfikmhoddligfbehkpomnbgblf

Please let me know if there's a way to solve this issue.
Thanks

Tony

Comment: We had tested your extension with the latest stable build of MS Edge Chromium browser  (Version 81.0.416.58 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and Win 10 OS build: 18363. This is the same OS build used by 1909. On our side, your extension is working. You can see this test result. https://imgur.com/a/f0ZiUaa Can you please inform us, which exact version of the MS Edge browser you are using for this test? It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Very strange, another user reported that Chrome on Windows doesn't work:

OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home
Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363

Google Chrome 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: 81_Win_92)
Revision e3225dafb0475864a1812a374d73a92e391635ac-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#936}
OS Windows 10 OS Version 1909 (Build 18363.778)
JavaScript V8 8.1.307.28
Flash 32.0.0.363 C:\Users\redt\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PepperFlash\32.0.0.363\pepflashplayer.dll

Comment: We can provide support for the MS Edge browser. As Google Chrome is a third party browser it is out of our support scope. Can you please inform us your testing result for the MS Edge Chromium browser?

Comment: We tested again with Edge Version 81.0.416.64 (Official build) (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home, version 1909, OS Version 18363.592. when we used the extension to recognize the song, that tab was silence and this is this audio file we captured via tabCapture.capture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c67vxku4ko20udp/music_test.webm?dl=0

Comment: Do you mean it should also work when the tab is silent or the song is paused? I think the song should get play at that time. I have seen that if the song is paused then it is not able to find the result even in the Google Chrome browser.

Comment: No, the music was still playing in that tab but no sound coming from that tab anymore and the extension get silence recording from that tab.

Comment: Not sure, do you mean the tab is on mute or the browser has some issue that stops the sound?

Comment: Yes, that tab is on mute or the browser has some issue that stops the sound.

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Comment: Till now I did not seen the issue when tab goes silent by itself. I will try to make some research about it and let you know about the result. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Ok thanks, please do let me know

Comment: We have another user reported this version of OS has the same issue: OS version is 1909 Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Hi @TonyLi I tested a few youtube songs, your extension works fine. I'm not able to reproduce this issue by my side. I'm using Windows 1909 too. Can you provide some songs link that can reproduce the issue? It also helps if you can provide some detailed repro steps.

Comment: It doesn't matter which songs are. Do you need some other information for the environment, do you think the language of the OS may be a factor?

Comment: @Tony Li Generally, I don't think the version or language of OS should be a factor for browsers API. Especially Edge Chromium has been independent from Windows. But you said this issue can be reproduced on 1909, Is this issue only appeared on 1909? Have you tested it in other version of windows and maybe also tested it in other machine?

Comment: If the issue can only be reproduced on 1909, then yes any detailed information of your environment like language would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if the issue is on other versions as well, we are collecting the reports from the users, but it is on the Simplified Chinese version of 1909 for sure, will you be able to test on that version?

Comment: I have just tested it on my personal computer (1909 with Chinese). Played a Chinese song. It worked well. So I guess this issue must be related to your native environment. Can you try reinstall Edge Chromium?

Comment: Here's the version detail from another user with this issue:
Version 83.0.4103.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)  
windows 10 64bit pro

Comment: Here's another user with this issue: OS: Win 8.1, ver. 6.3, build 9600  Edge: 83.0.478.58